# Unable to store array as a hash value

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to store an array (not array ref) in a hash but it is treating the array in *scalar context* and only storing the last value of array in the `$hash->{key}`.

```
use Data::Dumper;
$h->{'a'} = ( 'str_1', 'str_2' );
print Dumper $h;
```

**Output**:  `$VAR1 = { 'a' => 'str_2' };`

Why can't I store an array in hash-Key and access the array elements as  `$hash->{key}[index]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$h->{'a'} = [ 'str_1', 'str_2' ];
```

You can only store scalar as a hash value, and scalar can be simple value or array reference.

Check [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: please read the 1st line of my ques.(I m trying to store a array NOT ARRAY REF in a hash.)

Comment: @Bharat you can only store array ref. These are perl fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

Values of a hash have to be scalar values, cannot be arrays or hashes. So you need to use array reference as the value of `$h->{'a'}`:

```
$h->{'a'} = [ 'str_1', 'str_2' ];
```

and access them by using

```
$h->{'a'}->[0]; # for 'str_1'
$h->{'a'}->[1]; # for 'str_2'
```

By the way, as pointed out by @RobEarl, you also can use the following syntax

```
$h->{'a'}[0]; # for 'str_1'
$h->{'a'}[1]; # for 'str_2'
```

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for how to create and use different kind of references.