# Can array be value of Hash in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Now I need to get `{"teams":[1, 2, 35]}`, I wrote below code.

```
use JSON

my @array;
@array=(1, 2, 35);
my %hash;
$hash{"teams"}=@array;
$json = encode_json(\%hash);
print $json."\n";
```

but I just get `{"teams":3}`.

My question is can array be value of Hash in Perl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to store array as a hash value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932924/unable-to-store-array-as-a-hash-value) or [How do I store an array as a value in a Perl hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480241/how-do-i-store-an-array-as-a-value-in-a-perl-hash)

Comment: Please mark Sobrique answer as the correct one!

Comment: I think Sobrique answer is better than answers of Unable to store array as a hash value or How do I store an array as a value in a Perl hash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it can.

In `perl` multi-dimensional structures are done via references:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @array;
@array=(1, 2, 35);
my %hash;
$hash{"teams"}=\@array;
my $json = encode_json(\%hash);
print $json."\n";
```

The way this works is - your hash value can *only* be single scalar value. This should be a reference to an array.

This prints:

```
{"teams":[1,2,35]}
```

You could accomplish the same result with:

```
$hash{"teams"}=[@array];
```

Which is similar, in that it *copies* `@array` into an anonymous array.

The distinction comes if you re-use `@array`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @array;
@array=(1, 2, 35);
my %hash;
$hash{"teams"}=\@array;
@array = ( 3, 4, 5 ) ;
$hash{"more"} = \@array;
my $json = encode_json(\%hash);
print $json."\n";
```

This will actually print:

```
{"teams":[3,4,5],"more":[3,4,5]}
```

Because you've altered the array, and used a reference to the same array twice.

But if you do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @array;
@array=(1, 2, 35);
my %hash;
$hash{"teams"}=[@array];
@array = ( 3, 4, 5 ) ;
$hash{"more"} = [@array];
my $json = encode_json(\%hash);
print $json."\n";
```

You get:

```
{"more":[3,4,5],"teams":[1,2,35]}
```

You can see what's going on with the rather handy `Data::Dumper` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array;
@array = ( 1, 2, 35 );
my %hash;
$hash{"teams"} = @array;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

You'll see that what's in `hash` is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'teams' => 3
        };
{"teams":3}
```

Why you might ask? Well, because the entry in a hash can *only* be a scalar.

So you are accessing your array in a scalar context. And an array in a scalar context, prints it's number of elements:

```
print scalar @array; # prints 3
```

Which is what's happening in your example.

Comment: you may want to add the print output you are getting for other readers to see the difference